# How to connect to nethack from Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, artificial-intelligence, tty, nethack

I'm just starting an AI bot for the game `nethack`, and I can't bypass the 'human-check' that's in source.  The section of code I'm talking about is `nethack/sys/unix/unixunix.c`:

```
#ifdef TTY_GRAPHICS
    /* idea from rpick%ucqais@uccba.uc.edu
     * prevent automated rerolling of characters
     * test input (fd0) so that tee'ing output to get a screen dump still
     * works
     * also incidentally prevents development of any hack-o-matic programs
     */
    /* added check for window-system type -dlc */
    if (!strcmp(windowprocs.name, "tty"))
        if (!isatty(0))
        error("You must play from a terminal.");
#endif
```

I'm working in JavaScript, (more specifically Node.js), and due to the above, it won't let me play from the program, even though I'm spawning a bash shell child process and telling it to start `nethack`.  I need to figure out a way to bypass the above without recompiling the source.

The current code I'm using is:

```
"use strict";

var env = { TERM: 'tty' };
for (var k in process.env) {
    env[k] = process.env[k];
}

var terminal = require('child_process').spawn('bash', [], {
    env: env,
});

terminal.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

terminal.on('exit', function (code) {
        console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});

setTimeout(function() {
    terminal.stdin.write('nethack');
    terminal.stdin.end();
}, 1000);
```

The output of the program is:

```
stdout: You must play from a terminal.

child process exited with code 1
```

What Node.js/JavaScript (and not any other language or framework, if possible) black magic could I use to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, you might want to look into node's [TTY module](http://nodejs.org/api/tty.html). Also, [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/6fd25d16b250aa7d) might be of interest.

Comment: Yeah, I've checked out the TTY module: it seems that v0.6+ deprecate the `tty.open()` method, which may be something that I may want, but that method uses a deprecated `process.binding('stdio')` call, which I can't find any documentation on.  I'll check out the thread though.  Thanks.

Comment: Curious how this turned out for you? I'm also looking to get started doing something with NetHack and JavaScript.

Comment: @Jay While this *was* several years ago, I unfortunately didn't make any progress before I abandoned the concept. What I would do now would likely be to compile nethack from source removing that line or fake a TTY from node somehow. Node may or may not have such capabilities built in at this point, but honestly compile nethack from source seems like a good solution if you want to just hack locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's kind of a lame check because ptys will return true in *isatty()*.  Pty stands for [Pseudo terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal) which allows a program to pretend to be a terminal.  This is how Xterm and Screen work.  If that check didn't allow those programs through you wouldn't be able to play NetHack in them.

I've never used it but [pty.js](https://github.com/chjj/pty.js/) binds to exactly what you would use in C code and the interface makes sense.